# How are Rey and Kylo able to remain connected?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

As Rey is boarding the Millenium Falcon she and Kylo see each other again in the same way they had been throughout the movie.

We know that Snoke was the one connecting them since Kylo did not know how and he said it would have killed Rey for her to have done it.

Since Snoke is

> dead at the end of the film

How is it still possible for them to have still been connected?

Comment: He connected them, there is nothing said he needs to actively keep the connection up

Comment: Snoke claims to be the one connecting them, there is no evidence he is in fact connecting them.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177555/how-can-rey-and-kylo-ren-talk-to-each-other-mentally-and-see-each-others-backgr

Answer (score 8):

There is no canon information yet on how this is possible. Only fan speculation so far.

The possible theories (none of which have canon confirmation) are:

- Snoke was required to **establish** the connection. Once established, it does not require either his skill in the Force, or his power, to maintain (think of it as drilling through a wall - once you expend the effort to make the hole, you have that hole forever).
- Snoke isn't actually dead.

  This is less likely since the whole thematic strategy is to kill off all that made Star Wars good... err "old things" :P

  - As a particularly weird fan theory, a "Fight Club" like theory emerged that Snoke was just a manifestation of Kylo Ren's mind. In which case of course him being "dead" doesn't affect anything.
- Snoke just used Rey's and Ben's innate Force strength in the first place (and lied to them).

  - A subversion of this, he didn't do anything at all, and it was ALL 100% Ben and Rey, from when Rey got into Kylo Ren's head in Episode VII.

Comment: Snoke's dead, dude. "*I didn’t ultimately find out about **the death of Snoke** until very much closer to the shoot date. The information gets honed or given to you as you get closer just to hold on to it so it doesn’t get out there."* and *"We always knew [his death] was going to happen. It was in the script from the word go. Snoke’s obviously a fully digital character played by Andy Serkis on the day. **In terms of the actual moment of his death**, we have a few shots to build up to."* - http://www.slashfilm.com/the-last-jedi-lightsaber-battle/2/

Comment: @Valorum - this is Lucasfilm. They have been known to... how did Obi-Wan put it... have a "certain point of view" :)  Mind you, I find it unlikely, as I said

Comment: *through a wall :)

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like that. Snoke made the connection possible when they both were halfway across the Galaxy. 
In the end of the movie Kylo Ren and Rey are one the same planet and not that far apart. So in my mind Kylo Ren simply reached out to Rey and due to the very short distance between them he has no problem doing it.